# Conda creating large environments

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

We're in the process of cleaning up a bit of mess we created installing multiple versions of Conda across many hosts.

General breakdown of what we are doing is:

1. Loop through all Conda environments in versions installed and export them using --explicit method. Have same results using export command as well.
2. Delete existing Conda installations.
3. Install newer version of Conda using Miniconda3-4.6.14-Linux-x86_64.sh, would like to use newer but there are incompatibilities with our OS version/repos limiting us here.
4. Recreate environments with previously saved files "conda create -n <env_name> --file <explicit_env_file>

The problem is every environment, some which where less than 1mb in size before are 200+mb now. Have tried adding sleeps between environment creates, same result. Only way I have found to get them to there original size is creating them, removing them and recreating them on the new install. This is not workable as can't have Conda down for the hour+ that would take, which causes bigger problems.

I'm thinking this has to do with how Conda tracks previously installed packages to links them and somehow that is breaking with the pace we are creating them.

Anyone have an suggestions on how to accomplish this without duplicate packages inflating our enviroments? Not trying to limit responses, but things like use the latest mini-conda version or reduce the number of environments (around 80) are not options with our current infrastructure.

This is intended to be runnable through Ansible across multiple hosts, trying to keep update time as low as possible to minimize downtime.

Have tried different import/export strategies and adding sleeps between environment creates (up to 20 seconds)

Expecting that environment sizes would be the same pre and post upgrade.

Comment: What is the limitation with the OS version that requires old Miniconda? Why not Mambaforge? Generally, the Miniforge variants have broader OS support than Anaconda/Miniconda.

Comment: Corporate mandates, it's in a very secure environment where the OSs have to be approved/hardened. Current working with some servers running OL6 and others running OL7. Trying to remove workarounds put in place over time with Conda compatibility and get one single version. Personally would love to get rid of Conda completely if that was option, been nothing but a thorn in our side. Unfortunately have to replace like for like at this point.  Also have limited space on self hosted devices so a Conda install going from 6gb to 16gb causes devices to fill up quickly.

Comment: Unlike Anaconda, Conda Forge has continued building Miniforge variants with CentOS 6 compatibility, so I expect it would be compatible with both your systems. That is, you should be able to use a Conda/Mamba **base** that isn't 4 years old. But anyway, this is tangential to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After much playing around with this, I determined the behavior I'm seeing is a bug in this version, maybe others, of Miniconda. Essentially it seems that the cache doesn't get updated when add multiple environments, possibly a background task has the file locked.

The solution I found is to download the packages and populate the pkgs directory  and urls.txt as needed before creating the environments. Also makes the creation quicker in general as all the packages are cached at that point.